# Delphi XE2 / XE3 & Windows 8 Tablets / Phones

Tags: delphi, windows-8, app-store, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe3

Is it possible to develop apps for Windows 8 tablets and phones using Delphi XE2 or XE3? I think XE3 ust supports UI. I am not sure if we can create apps for Win8 tablets using Delphi. I have read somewhere we need to use Prism XE3 with Visual Studio. I don't want to purchase / upgrade to XE3 just because of this. I believe we can develop even using XE2 but not sure.

Also, does anyone know if Microsoft accepts apps to appstore which are written in Delphi?

Thanks.

-K

Comment: When you talk about 'Windows 8 tablets', I suppose you are referring to 'Windows RT'? Also, to my knowledge, the term 'App Store' is Apple-specific...

Comment: I mean ARM. Well, I am not sure about Tablets or RT versions. I just want to know if there will be ARM tablets in the market? By "App Store" I mean windows 8 apps store.

Comment: Here is the link: http://www.embarcadero.com/products/rad-studio/windows-8-development

Comment: Emba don't have a compiler for ARM yet. And even if they did, they can't meet Windows Store requirements yet. So no WinRT even for x86.

Answer (score 5):

The Delphi XE2 and XE3 fact sheets, available at [Embarcadero](http://www.embarcadero.com/delphi), clearly mention which operating systems and CPUs the IDEs support, and WinRT and ARM are not among the ones listed. So the answer would be "No".

Comment: So there is no need to upgrade to XE3. Because this looks like "cheating". I would expect Embarcadero to give support for WinRT and ARM. There will be lots of tablets which use these chipsets i believe.

Comment: And they will. It's hard to support something that wasn't released when either XE2 or XE3 were released, and there have been plans announced on the roadmap to support mobile development. As far as whether or not you have a need to upgrade, only you can make that choice, and SO is not the place to discuss it.

Comment: EMB need to sort some legal hops placed by Microsoft to control Win8 applications market. In its current form it is impossible for third party compilers to do anything in the RT space.